# What is the relationship between concept of algebra in measure theory and algebra over a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, measure-theory

In measure theory, an algebra on a set $X$ is a collection $\mathcal A\subset\mathcal P(X)$ with properties

> (1) $X\in\mathcal A$
> (2) For any $A\in\mathcal A,\ X\setminus A\in\mathcal A$
> (3) For any $A,B\in\mathcal A$, $A\cup B\in\mathcal A$.

In abstract algebra, an algebra over a commutative ring $R$ is a pair $(A,\cdot)$
where $A$ is a $R$-module and $\cdot:\ A\times A\to A$ is a bilinear operation.

I wonder if there is any relationship between the concept of algebra is used in measure theory with the algebra over a commutative ring, or any other concept of algebra is used in abstract algebra ? Thanks.

Comment: In measure theory it is called [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Σ-algebra), and not "algebra", like in abstract algebra. So these two definitions are different. About your question "*or any other concept of algebra is used*", I think there are many ways, but your question is too vague.

Comment: In the book "Real analysis : theory of measure and integration" by J. Yeh,  the author defined both concepts algebra and $\sigma$-algebra , where an algebra has the similar properties to $\sigma$-algebra except the closedness under union is applied for finite collection.

Comment: Then it is still different from the definition in abstract algebra.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a connection. Given a set $X$, the collection of its subsets $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is a commutative, unital ring with respect to the following operations:

$A+B:= A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$

$AB:=A\cap B$

i.e the operations are symmetric difference and intersection. The zero element is $\emptyset$, and identity is $X$. All the ring axioms are easy to verify. And since this is a ring of prime characteristic $2$, it trivially becomes an algebra over the field $\mathbb{F_2}$.

Now, as you can check, a subset $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ is an algebra of sets (with respect to the measure theory definition) if and only if it is a subalgebra over $\mathbb{F_2}$ in the algebraic sense. (equivalently, a subring)

A nice application of this is that it can be proved in a purely algebraic way that the cardinality of any finite algebra of sets (even if $X$ itself is infinite) is a power of $2$.

Comment: wow, it's really fascinating, thanks for your great answer.